# linq to sql for beginner

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my first time when I want to do linq to sql, I am looking for good video right from the beginning how to put that in vs 2010 if anyone has a good source I would appreciate it very much, I searched already but did not find anything good yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a good blog post from Jesse Liberty + info about a neat LINQ test tool called LINQPad.  He's writing a new book on LINQ & reactive extensions for C# 5.

```
  http://jesseliberty.com/2011/07/19/linq-pad-vs-visual-studio-for-learning-linq/
```

... and here's the tool that is packed with examples that you can run + play with to see results (way faster than attempting to do the same in VS2010)

```
   http://www.linqpad.net/
```

Comment: What did that have to do with his question on Linq to SQL videos?

Comment: @George Stoker.  Did you check out the jesseliberty site?  The examples in both of these places often use LINQ-to-SQL.  Both sites are suited to beginners *and* there's a flavour of what is yet to come with reactive extensions.  It was an effort to help out, and not just provide a yes/no answer, but to provide background that a beginner might find useful.  I've certainly found value in both areas.  That was the relevance for me.  Could you be a little more specific about your objection?  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, the OP asked for 'videos'. There are already many questions on SO that deal with non-video resources to learn Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: @George Stocker that's very literal of you.  Was it purely a literal question, or one which was saying 'I need the best way to crack this egg... video is usually good that.'  So, knowing others would fill the 'video' gaps, I thought, hey, have you tried 'interactive'?  In the bottom right of SO there's 'Related' links.  My post was descriptive version of the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as videos, there are a [whole slew of them](http://www.asp.net/linq/videos) on the official ASP.NET site.

If you're looking for an example of applications that use Linq-to-SQL, you may want to try the [Nerddinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) application.

Answer (score 0):

This site is pretty good, I use it a lot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746